# Delete row from dynamic table

Tags: javascript

I have created a table dynamically using Javascript .i am able to add rows but not able to delete.

**MyHtml:**

```
<div id="Mutipletextboxhandler" style="text-align: center;" class="step" name="Mutipletextboxhandler">
    </div> 
        <input id="Hidden" type="hidden" runat="server" value="" />
        <input id="btnAddexisting" type="button" value="Insert item" onclick="AddmultipleTextBox()" />
```

And my Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AddmultipleTextBox() {
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicmultipleTextBox("");
            document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").appendChild(div);
        }

        function GetDynamicmultipleTextBox(value) {

            return '<table id="d"><tr><td><input name = "mDynamicTextBox1" type="text" value = "' + value + '" /></td><td><input name = "mDynamicTextBox2" type="text" value = "' + value + '" /></td'+
            '<td><input name = "mDynamicTextBox3" type="text" value = "' + value + '" /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemovemultipleTextBox(this)" /></td>' +
            '</tr></table>'
       }
    **//Problamatic Function is below:**
        function RemovemultipleTextBox(div) {        
            document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").removeAttributeNode(div);
            }
        function RecreateDynamicmultipleTextboxes() {
            var mvalues = eval('<%=mValues%>');
            if (mvalues != null) {
                var html = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < mvalues.length; i++) {
                    html += "<div>" + GetDynamicmultipleTextBox(mvalues[i]) + "</div>";
                }
                document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").innerHTML = html;
            }
        }
      window.onload = RecreateDynamicmultipleTextboxes;
</script>
```

**Question**-Addition of rows is working fine but when i delete ,then 
"NO Such interface supported" Error is coming.
Its working fine if i have no tables and only one texbox.
Somebody please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").removeChild(div)`

**Update:**

you can update your funtion as something like this

```
function RemovemultipleTextBox(div) {
  while((div.tagName != "HTML" || div.tagName != "TABLE") && div.id != "d") {
    div = div.parentNode
  }
  if(div.tagName == "TABLE") {
    document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").removeChild(div.parentNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too.Its working for single textbox outside of table elements.here it is giving error"NotFoundError"

Comment: removeChild just allow to delete the direct child element
i updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

edit:
Let's redo this with a proper handler.
Step 1: Add a class to your input button and remove the onclick.

```
<input class="button-remove" type="button" value="Remove" />
```

Step 2: Add this logic every place you call `GetDynamicmultipleTextBox`. We create the box into a variable, then select the button out of this box and add an event listener.

```
var box = GetDynamicmultipleTextBox();
box.querySelector('.button-remove').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var button = event.target,
        div = button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").removeChild(div);
});
```

Step 3: `document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").appendChild(box);`

Comment: Do you mean something like this: function RemovemultipleTextBox(div) {

        document.getElementById("Mutipletextboxhandler").removeChild(event.target)
        } ? Its also giving same error sir

Comment: Added some code. removeAttributeNode is to remove attributes from html elements, not to remove an html node for another node.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Sir.but now this Event is showing as "Undefined" while debugging.The error I am getting is  :JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Stuff like this is why I never insert whole tables into innerHTML. Alrighty i'll update again.

Comment: Actually I need a table with three columns on button click and this was something I could comeup with.I am not sure of any other method .So forgive my understanding of javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.cant mark two as answers.but great thanks.upvoted